# Problem in positioning in navigation bar using css

Tags: html, css, css-position, navbar, pseudo-element

I am making a navbar of an e-commerce website and I want this little line to display like it is displayed below "Home", when the user is in that particular page.

[image]

When I write the code, this happens-

[image: My navbar]

For some reason, that little bar, starts just after that Nav button ends.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #121212;
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px 80px;
  background: #121212;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

#navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

#navbar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
}

#navbar li a:hover,
#navbar li a.active {
  color: #e50914;
}

#navbar li a.active::after {
  content: "";
  width: 60%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #e50914;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -6px;
  position: 0;
}

.logo {
  width: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="header">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" class="logo"></a>
    <div>
      <ul id="navbar">
        <li><a class="active" href="why.html">Why Snap Smile</a></li>
        <li><a href="solutions.html">Solutions</a></li>
        <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-headset"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position: 0` is not a valid CSS property:value pair.  You have the position set to `absolute` which is correct, but then you overwrite it with an invalid property.  So I deleted it.

Next step is to give the `::after` element the same `left` value as the padding on the `#navbar li`, *et voila* you have aligned active underline.

In order to get proper alignment with the text, you have to remember that the underline is taken out of the document flow with `position: absolute`, so it won't take account for the `padding` that the text is in. We have to manually add the same left-side padding value the text has as a `left` position on the underline.

```
#navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 20px; /* has left padding of 20px */
  position: relative;
}

#navbar li a.active::after {
  content: "";
  width: 60%;
  left: 20px; /* aligning manually with the same value */
  height: 3px;
  background: #e50914;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -6px;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #121212;
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px 80px;
  background: #121212;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

#navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

#navbar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
}

#navbar li a:hover,
#navbar li a.active {
  color: #e50914;
}

#navbar li a.active::after {
  content: "";
  width: 60%;
  left: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #e50914;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -6px;
}

.logo {
  width: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="header">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" class="logo"></a>
    <div>
      <ul id="navbar">
        <li><a class="active" href="why.html">Why Snap Smile</a></li>
        <li><a href="solutions.html">Solutions</a></li>
        <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-headset"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it worked. Can you please explain how the padding of the 'li' element affected the active underline?

Comment: Good point, I added some explanation to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a quick fix.

```
   #navbar li a.active::after{
      content: "";
      width: 60%;
      height: 3px;
      background: #e50914;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -6px;
      position: 0;
      transform:translate(-135px); // x and y controls
    }
```